# How to copy intl.so to /usr/lib/php/extensions

Tags: macos, moodle

I wanted to try Moodle (LMS) on my computer. It requires intl extension. 
I used `sudo port install php71-intl` and successfully installed php71-intl. But it also installed php71 and other dependencies on /opt/local/. 
I am using Mac built-in php. Its directories are

```
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
/usr/bin/php
```

I intended to copy the `/opt/local/lib/php71/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so` to `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303`. But terminal said Operation not permitted.

I tried `sudo pecl install intl` but failed with make error. 
This method `sudo port install php71-intl` can install the intl.so successfully but in its own direcotry.

So how I can copy the intl.so? Thank you!

Comment: try `rsync -av /opt/local/lib/php71/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/` otherwise take a look here: https://www.cnet.com/news/using-the-os-x-terminal-instead-of-the-finder-to-copy-files/

Comment: Terminal still says `Operation not permitted`

Comment: did you tryed the rsync command with sudo? So like this: `sudo rsync -av /opt/local/lib/php71/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/`

Comment: Yes. complete message is: `rsync: mkstemp "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/.intl.so.Xj1MTr" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 414478 bytes  received 42 bytes  829040.00 bytes/sec
total size is 414320  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]`

Comment: Most likely you have too few rights or the folder is backed up by the system. Attempt to create a file in the destination folder with the same name and then fill it with the contents of the other.

Comment: I tried `sudo mkdir a` and `sudo touch a.txt`  in `/usr/lib/php/extension/`. But it always says `Operation not permitted`. Some answers say I need to disable Mac System Security but I don't wanna do that for being afraid that would hurt my computer. Also I reckon that doesn't matter because we use `brew install` command , it will modify /usr/lib/ without changing System Security.

Comment: As I told you have not enough permissions to edit this folde. You souls take a look who the owner of this folder structure is and logon as this user. For example: `sudo su www-http` you can take a look who is the owner with the `ls -a` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable SIP to do that. First, restart your Mac and before OS starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery. From the Utilities menu, select Terminal and at the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return: csrutil disable

Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled. From the menu, select Restart. You can re-enable SIP by following the above steps, but using csrutil enable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Find this file "environment.xml" and comment all lines that have "intl" and reload the page. Continue button appears and installation completes without any error. My instance started working like charm, I use it to test out and create courses with SCORM packages, no errors yet.

[environment.xml file is located in "admin" folder of moodle directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFORZ.png)